APS Hierarchy empty for 2d views
I have been using successfully APS ModelDerivative API to retrieve the hierarchy of REVIT model elements using this end point (both in 3d views and 2d views):
   https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/{urn}/metadata/{modelGuid}
However in one specific model, for all 2D views the returned hierarchy is empty. response bellow...
{"data": {"type": "objects","objects": [{}]}}
similar behavior happens when querying for properties (successful call but no data retrieved).
3D views work ok. The strange behavior is only for 2d views.
tried to remove some views, add new ones, republish the model, download an upload the model to another ACC project, but the behavior remains the same.
Any one has experience this behavior and as a clue in how to solve it?
Thanks!

Can you consistently reproduce this with a specific model? Would you be able to provide such a model for us? You can reach out to us here to do that: https://aps.autodesk.com/contact-support

Shared some information by email to aps team. Ref: 20275. Can you access?

OK. I see a colleague is handling that
